# What values to use for a Redis memory budget?

Tags: memory-management, redis

I'm working on an app that will be using Redis to store some end user session state details. There will be many tens to hundred of millions of key/value ([unordered sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets)) with [expiries](http://redis.io/commands/expire) set (to the second). To gauge whether or not my existing Redis installation will run into memory exhaustion problems, I need to create a budget for my app's expected and worst case Redis memory usage.

The size of the raw data, number of keys, key value pair lifespan, etc. is well know and in the calculation spreadsheet.   For Redis specific things, like expiry value size, I just have wild guesses.

**For my memory budget calculation, what values should I use for:**

- *per key* redis overhead (bytes?  percent?)
- *per key* expiry size (seconds, not ms)
- *per key* set size/overhead
- *per set* item size/overhead

*(Other per key or data type information might be helpful to others.)*

Comment: Don't forget: will you use dumps? As making the dump consumes RAM, you will need more if you use them.

Comment: @zenbeni: Have not forgotten that little detail...